# Is there a principled ANOVA-like approach when a "subject" factor forms a symmetric 2D matrix?

Tags: anova, inference, repeated-measures, matrix

I have a dataset where the dependent variable is a similarity measure between any 2 data channels, lets call it S(i,j), with a few dozen simultaneously recorded channels (so there are quite a few possible pairs). S is symmetric, such that S(i,j)==S(j,i). Therefore, the distribution of unique pairs to analyze is a triangular matrix, minus the diagonal.

There are many trials, so many estimates of S(i,j), and there is an additional factor D that influences S.

I would like to test whether D influences S, and if so, for which pairs of (i,j).

I would like to analyze these data with an ANOVA-like approach, but the data don't seem to fit into any standard ANOVA paradigm that I am familiar with.

It isn't really possible to consider i and j as separate factors, because they are interchangeable.

One possible approach would be to treat pairs of i,j as unique subjects, but clearly they are not independent of each other. For an example, if S(m,n) is large and S(m,o) is large, one would expect that S(n,o) is also large (I don't really expect to correct for this covariance except for concern about the error assumptions in the tests of the effect of D).

Another approach would be to analyze each pair as if the others don't exist, and worry about correcting for false-positives at a later stage.

Are there any other suggestions for approaching this problem, or suggestions for approaching the data in the less than ideal ways I already mentioned?

Comment: i can't think of anything else. It looks like you have got it covered.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I appreciate the vote of confidence, though I would also appreciate if those more experienced than me could weigh in on the relative merit or potential pitfalls of the two less-than-ideal solutions I gave. Thanks much.